# How to perform data fetch on button click on a built in html page using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am new to Selenium and I am trying to mimic user actions on a site to fetch data from a built in html page on button click. I am able to populate all the field details, but button click is not working, it looks like js code not running.

I tried many options like adding wait time, Action chain etc but it didnt work, i am providing site and code i have written.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www1.nseindia.com/products/content/derivatives/equities/historical_fo.htm")
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
```

assigned values to all the other fields

```
driver.find_element_by_id('rdDateToDate').click()

Dfrom = driver.find_element_by_id('fromDate')
Dfrom.send_keys("02-Oct-2020")

Dto = driver.find_element_by_id('toDate')
Dto.send_keys("08-Oct-2020")

innerHTML = driver.execute_script("document.ready")
sleep(5)

getdata_btn = driver.find_element_by_id('getButton')
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(getdata_btn).click().click().perform()
```

Comment: I even tried semi automation, by only opening page using selenium and then manually tried to fill data and clicked button, but even then its not fetching data that it does fetch by full manual actions. Is there a constraint on website that automation is restricted? somebody pls help.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using a full xpath.

```
chrome.get("https://www1.nseindia.com/products/content/derivatives/equities/historical_fo.htm")
time.sleep(2)
print("click")
fullxpath = "/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/form/div[19]/p[2]/input"
chrome.find_element_by_xpath(fullxpath).click()
```

I have tried the button clicking and it worked with XPath ... I though its because of someone used the ID twice on a website, but I can not find it ... so i have no idea whats going wrong there ...

Good luck :)

Comment: I tried full xpath, but got error saying its image not button, not sure how to find and click the button. It was happening manually but not able to automate. Thanks for response.

Comment: Try to copy paste the code i given you and see if thatcone works

Comment: I already tried and getting error  "ElementClickInterceptedException: element click intercepted: Element <input type="image" class="getdata-button" src="/common/images/btn-get-data.gif" id="getButton" name="getButton"> is not clickable at point (255, 548).Other element would receive the click: <li class="" style="border-right: 1px solid #424240;    color: #F0F0F0;    float: left;    font-size: 1.2em;    font-weight: bold;    width: auto;    z-index: 100;">...</li>
  (Session info: chrome=86.0.4240.75)"